# Script to find text datatypes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a few thousand tables in my SQL Server instance, and I need to start converted old deprecated datatypes into the new version (text to varchar(max)). Is it possible to script this out so I can just run select statement to find all of these without manually going through each of the tables in the database instance? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]),
  OBJECT_NAME([object_id]),
  name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE system_type_id IN (35,99);
```

You can even do this to generate a set of commands to change the tables:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' 
  + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id]))
  + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + ' ' + CASE system_type_id WHEN 99 THEN 'N' ELSE '' END
  + 'VARCHAR(MAX);'
FROM sys.columns
WHERE system_type_id IN (35,99);
```

Of course you'll also want to deal with nullability etc. but this is just a starting point.

Comment: Awesome Aaron (thanks for answering both my questions today). Even giving the alter statement, I wish I could give you extra points!!!

Comment: I tried running my conversion and it says I can't convert the 'image' datatype to varchar(max) or nvarchar(max). Should it be changed to varbinary(max)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) views for this.

**Example**

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'text'
```

Comment: I actually recommend avoiding the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views : https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) TableName, c.name ColumnName,
    t.name, c.max_length, c.precision, c.scale
FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
WHERE t.name = 'text' 
ORDER BY c.OBJECT_ID;
```

Comment: Why do you need max_length, precision and scale when you know the type is going to be text? Why aren't you using AS or = for your aliases? Why do you need the join when you can easily derive the type_id from sys.columns? What good does the order by do for you? Why are you ignoring schema, when there could be two tables with the same name under different schema?

Comment: I wrote it in a generic way to demonstrate it. You can explore those tables and get more details as needed.